# Array swap an Array

Tags: c++, arrays

Write a function called swap which has a prototype of void swap (int&, int&); to swap two neighbors that are not in increasing order.

here what i have so far

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int array[]={34, 21, 89,56,78,2,14,56,0,99};
    int countComparisons=0;

    cout<<"Original List: ";
    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) cout<<a[i]<<" "; cout<<endl; //print array
    for (int start=0; start<=9;start++) //outer loop
    {
        for (int i=0; i<9; i++)  //inner loop
        {
            countComparisons++;
            if (array[i]>array[i+1])
            {

        }
    }
    cout<<"\nFinal List: ";
    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) cout<<a[i]<<" "; cout<<endl; //print array
    cout <<"Number of comparions "<<countComparisons<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
Original List: 34 21 89 56 78 2 14 56 0 99
swapped 34 with 21
21 34 89 56 78 2 14 56 0 99
swapped 89 with 56
21 34 56 89 78 2 14 56 0 99
swapped 89 with 78
21 34 56 78 89 2 14 56 0 99
swapped 89 with 2
21 34 56 78 2 89 14 56 0 99
swapped 89 with 14
21 34 56 78 2 14 89 56 0 99
swapped 89 with 56
21 34 56 78 2 14 56 89 0 99
swapped 89 with 0
21 34 56 78 2 14 56 0 89 99
swapped 78 with 2
21 34 56 2 78 14 56 0 89 99
swapped 78 with 14
21 34 56 2 14 78 56 0 89 99
swapped 78 with 56
21 34 56 2 14 56 78 0 89 99
swapped 78 with 0
21 34 56 2 14 56 0 78 89 99
swapped 56 with 2
21 34 2 56 14 56 0 78 89 99
swapped 56 with 14
21 34 2 14 56 56 0 78 89 99
swapped 56 with 0
21 34 2 14 56 0 56 78 89 99
swapped 34 with 2
21 2 34 14 56 0 56 78 89 99
swapped 34 with 14
21 2 14 34 56 0 56 78 89 99
swapped 56 with 0
21 2 14 34 0 56 56 78 89 99
swapped 21 with 2
2 21 14 34 0 56 56 78 89 99
swapped 21 with 14
2 14 21 34 0 56 56 78 89 99
swapped 34 with 0
2 14 21 0 34 56 56 78 89 99
swapped 21 with 0
2 14 0 21 34 56 56 78 89 99
swapped 14 with 0
2 0 14 21 34 56 56 78 89 99
swapped 2 with 0
0 2 14 21 34 56 56 78 89 99

Final List: 0 2 14 21 34 56 56 78 89 99
Number of comparions 90

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.031 s
Press any key to continue.
```

any idea how to do this . i never learn how to swap the array

thank you

Comment: Just give me your professors email and I'll be more than glad to write it for you and send it to him/her.

Comment: Your assignment does not match up **at all** with your code.

Comment: where is swap(int&, int&) in your code?

Comment: Sounds like it's calling for the core of a bubble sort function.

Comment: linda, racist comments are not tolerated here. I have deleted both comments making insinuations about another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Write a function called `swap` which has a prototype of `void swap (int&, int&);` to swap two neighbors that are not in increasing order.

Pseudocode:

```
void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    if b is smaller than a
    {
        store a in some new variable c
        store b in a
        store c in b
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and than use that instead the `if-block` after `countComparisons++` in your source ...

Comment: not that it actually maters for the original question, but you can make it more general by adding a predicate to the prototype and replacing if(b is smaller than a) with if(predicate(a,b))

Comment: @Marius ~ While you are quite clever, the level of the OP is not being considered ...